# Integral of square root function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I have a function $f(x)=  $$ \frac{ax^3 + 2ax}{\sqrt{x^4+4x^2+4}}$$ ,$a >0

And i'm given that $f(x) $= g'(x)

and also that one of the interception points between the function f(x) and the function g(x) is x=0

and i need to show that the function $g(x) is: $g(x)=2x^2
How can i do such a thing? can someone give me a hint so i can start?

Comment: Can you use $u$-substitution to integrate $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=\frac{ax^3 + 2ax}{\sqrt{x^4+4x^2+4}}=\frac{ax^3 + 2ax}{\sqrt{(x^2+2)^2}}=\frac{ax^3 + 2ax}{x^2+2}=ax$.

Your turn !